# About dividing into subproblems for akka actor model using scala

Tags: scala, hash, akka, actor, sha256

I am doing a project involving finding a suffix string given a prefix --for instance, "aaa", so that that its hashed value (SHA256) has a certain pattern -- for example, starting with "123".

My method of finding the required hash key is to generate the suffix string in an ordered way: first try all the string with one character -- basically it goes through the ASCII printable code chart, 95 trials in total. If the required hash key is not found, then try all the string with two characters (95*95 trails)... and so on so forth.

I am also required to use akka actor model to let multiple actors get involved in solving this problem concurrently. (The number of actors is an input)

Any idea about how to efficiently divide the total problem to multiple actors using this pattern? Or anyone has a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group your workers under a [BalancingPool](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html#BalancingPool) which will automatically distribute work to idle actors, with the manager and worker actors using [work pulling](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/akka-work-pulling-pattern/) to prevent the mailbox from growing too large.

1. The manager accepts two message types: `work-request` and `work-complete`.  `Work-request` is called by a worker when it has completed `X` tasks (where `X` is, say, 10), signalling the manager to add `X` more tasks to the `BalancingPool`.  `Work-complete` is called when a worker has found an appropriate string prefix, at which point the manager sends out a `stop` command to the `BalancingPool` instructing it to immediately terminate and to also terminate its workers.  Aside from this, the manager is responsible for initially filling the `BalancingPool` with sufficient prefixes for the workers to test (say, 20 * workerCount), and refilling the pool every time it receives a `work-request` message.
2. The workers accept one message type: `test-prefix`, which contains a string prefix for the worker to test.  It also needs to maintain a count of messages that it has received and processed, and when this count reaches `X` then it is zeroed and the worker sends a `work-request` message to the manager.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I did not explain the requirement very clearly. There is essentially only one prefix as an input, but there will be many prefix-suffix strings meeting the requirement of   beginning with "123". The goal is to let actors work together to find as many such strings as possible in same amount of time or to minimize the time to find same amount of such strings.

Comment: I kinda have a thought and I want to ask for your opinion. In my algorithm, I construct a mapping that transform all the suffix (starting from a string containing one character) to the integer domain (from 1 to +inf). I am thinking to use the remainder function to divide the job to all actors evenly. Say I have 3 actors, then actor1 takes the work of {1,4,7,...,1+3k}; actor2 takes the work of {2,5,8,...,2+3k}; actor3 takes the work of {3,6,9,...,3+3k} for k={1,2,3,...}. Following this pattern and assuming there are m actors, the ith actor takes the work subset {i+m*k}.

Comment: @ChenChen That's certainly a reasonable approach, Akka actually comes with a [hashing router](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html#ConsistentHashingPool_and_ConsistentHashingGroup) that you may want to use in order to avoid putting routing logic in the manager